Flipper 0.237.0 Failed to start client connection
I'm encountering an issue with Flipper 0.237.0 while trying to connect to a device (ID: '23021RAAEG - 13 - API 33'). The error message I'm getting is:
enter image description here
Connection to 'דומינוס פיצה' on '23021RAAEG - 13 - API 33' failed
Failed to start client connection: Failed to exchange certificate with דומינוס פיצה on 23021RAAEG - 13 - API 33: Error: Warning: error while verifying CSR self-signature Error while verifying certificate request self-signature 405C5CDC01000000:error:05800091:x509 certificate routines:X509_REQ_verify_ex:unsupported version:crypto/x509/x_all.c:47: 405C5CDC01000000:error:05800091:x509 certificate routines:X509_REQ_verify_ex:unsupported version:crypto/x509/x_all.c:47:
Has anyone encountered this issue? How can I fix it, especially the certificate verification error and the "NO APPLICATION SELECTED" issue?

You can just downgrade openSSL to 3.3.x while waiting for the fix with openSSL 3.4.0
Reference : https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/5680

I guess the issues can be related to Android NDK using the OpenSSL version 3.2.x. Looking forward when it upgrades OpenSSL to 3.4.0.
NDK git log : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/ndkports/+log
